# All 4 Digit Combinations (0-9) Using Python

Tags: python

Figured it out. Thanks. Here is a list of all possible 4 digit pins

```
file = open("E:\Text.txt","r+")
for l in range(0,10):
    for m in range(0,10):
        for n in range(0,10):
            for o in range(0,10):
                file.write(str(l) + str(m) + str(n) + str(o) + "\n")
                print(str(l) + str(m) + str(n) + str(o))
file.close()
```

Comment: Open the file and use the option `file=f` in the `print()` call.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: There are many tutorials on reading and writing files. SO is not a substitute for learning the basics.

Comment: Get out of the habit of iterating over indexes. Iterate over the list with `for l in k:`

Comment: the easiest is redirecting the output itself `python myfile.py > output.txt`

Comment: This wasn't for some class or anything important. Literally, the first thing I've done besides "Hello World". Pretty sure SO is used for learning in general. I wouldn't be here if the tutorials helped. I was looking for someone to tell me where I went wrong because I rewrote this so many times, watched and looked over videos and comments, and still couldn't figure it out. Took way more time than it should of but I guess that's what learnings about. Figure it out so when you come to something related the next time its easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
with open('demo.txt', 'w') as sourceFile:
    # your code here...
    print('Hello, Python!', file = sourceFile)
```

Comment: use `with` instead of separate `open` and `close` calls.